# Save a file on a usb drive from an android device

Tags: android

I am trying to save a file to a usb drive from my android app. I used to do this aback in 2013 (7 years ago the API was different and methods were also different)

```
File file = new File("Environment.getRootDirectory().getParent()"+"storage/usbport1/cvxvxvxv/Data");
        if(!file.exists())
            file.mkdirs();
```

Environment class only has method that are useful in my case:

getExternalStorage()
getExternalPublicStorage()
getRootDirectory // this seems to point to system instead of root.

Comment: getExternalFilesDirs()[1]/[2] depending on micro sd card inserted.

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/11/storage-situation-removable-storage.html